# If f is a function of $x$ and $t$ where $x$ itself is a function of time does this mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=0$?

Tags: calculus

$\frac{\partial f(x(t),t)}{\partial x}=0$?

I suspect it probably doesn't but I can't justify it to myself.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$
\frac{\partial f(x(t),t)}{\partial x}=\frac{\frac{\partial f(x(t),t)}{\partial t}}{\frac{\partial x(t)}{\partial t}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

The equation $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =0$$ means that $f$ has no dependence on its first variable. Thus $f(x_1,t)=f(x_2,t)$ for all possible values of $x_1,x_2,t$.